# How do I execute a jenkins cli command on localhost?

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-api

I want to run this command on the jenkins server after jenkins is installed for the first time:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\jenkins-cli.jar' -s https://localhost list-plugins
```

When I try to hit localhost or 127.0.0.1 (jenkins is setup to listen on port 80) I get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found.
```

How do I execute jenkins cli commands in a terminal session on the master?

Comment: If your jenkins is listening on port 80 shouldn't you be using `http://localhost` instead ?

Comment: @ben5556 Yeah 443 whatever that's not the issue though